# How to Implement TablePersoController

Tags: sapui5

I am calling the below mentioned Odata Service and displaying the data in a table.

I want to implement the hiding column feature with TablePersocontroller but I have no clue how to start or what are the steps.

http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=json

I have created the JS view , so if help is in Javascript that would be great.

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TablePerso/preview) example in SAPUI5 Demokit's Explored tab.

You will need to provide `PersoService.js` with columns data, it will automatically handle hide/display of columns based on columns selection in `TablePersoDialog` provided by `TablePersoController`.